# SCP doesn't work when echo in .bashrc?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I have two users in Fedora:

1. Wani
2. root (quite obvious!)

My contents of .bashrc of user Wani are:

```
# .bashrc
echo "Hello"
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
```

Now after logging into root, I type the following commands:

```
[root@Dell Wani]# touch try.txt
[root@Dell Wani]# service sshd start
[root@Dell Wani]# scp try.txt Wani@localhost:~/
Wani@localhost's password: 
Hello
[root@Dell Wani]#
```

Now I log into Wani, and type:

```
[Wani@Dell ~]$ cat try.txt
cat: try.txt: No such file or directory
[Wani@Dell ~]$
```

Now I again log into root and type the same command with `-v`:

```
[root@Dell Wani]# scp -v morph.log Wani@localhost:
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host localhost, user Wani, command scp -v -t -- .
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.6 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-     with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
Wani@localhost's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env XMODIFIERS = @im=none
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- .
Hello
[root@Dell Wani]# debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status      reply      0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 1664, received 1976 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 22961.5, received 27266.8
debug1: Exit status 0
```

(And after I press Enter)

```
[root@Dell Wani]#
```

Can anyone please shed some light as to what exactly happened here? Why did the file not get copied to Wani from root?

Comment: What about `cp`? Does `cp try.txt ~Wani/` work?

Comment: It is indeed possible that interactive commands or spurious output from your `.bashrc` could ruin some noninteractive scenarios. Try making the code conditional on `case $- in *i*` or some such.

Comment: @nneonneo: That works. Actually, even If I have the two users on different computers, the file doesn't get copied!

Comment: All the posts I have seen describe WHY this problem exists in various bashrc files, etc.  However, when SCP/STFP to a machine you DON'T OWN and CANNOT change the startup scripts, what is the solution then???

Comment: I ended up redirecting all echos to stderr. Works, but...

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Using `echo` in a `.bashrc` will break `scp`, as `scp` expects to see its protocol data over the stdin/stdout channels. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527 for more discussion on this issue.

There's a few workarounds available:

- Condition on the 'interactive' flag (e.g. `case $- in *i*` as suggested by tripleee)
- Use the `tty` utility to detect an interactive shell (e.g. `if tty > /dev/null` or `if [ -t 0 ]`)
- Check the value of `$SSH_TTY`

I suppose you should use whichever one works for you. I don't know what the best (most portable/most reliable) option is, unfortunately.

Comment: Just to clarify the "case" command would be: `case $- in *i*) echo This is safe since the shell is interactive; esac`

Comment: `shopt` is also an alternative

Comment: Since my host is always accessed over SSH, SSH_TTY is always set. Using the `-t 0` condition worked well for me. I use the following function all over my bashrc now.

```safe_echo() {
   if [[ -t 0 ]];then
       echo -e "$*"
   fi
}
```

Comment: `if [[ "$SSH_TTY" == */dev/pts/* ]] ; then` inside if put your content which prints to stdout , then scp will work fine.

Comment: @BeatingBytes & @Sandip Bhattacharya, `[[` isn't portable and I also don't think it's posix.  Try this in the `dash` shell:  `if [[ 0 = 0 ]]; then echo x; else echo y; fi`.  You get, `dash: 3: [[: not found`.

Comment: `$SSH_TTY` check will not work when you first ssh to some host then do scp, such as:

`$  ssh myhost`
`$  scp  myfile  anotherhost:~`

since $SSH_TTY got set on the first ssh, and never been reset in the following command(s).

Comment: You just saved me a lot of frustration thank you.

Answer (score 21):

To add to nneonneo's options, you can also condition with the interactive flag with

```
if [[ $- =~ "i" ]]
```

which I think is possibly the clearest way in bash.

Comment: `[[` isn't portable and I also don't think it's posix.  Try this in the `dash` shell:  `if [[ 0 = 0 ]]; then echo x; else echo y; fi`.  You get, `dash: 3: [[: not found`.

Answer (score 18):

This works for me,
In `.bashrc` add first line as:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
    return
fi
```

https://superuser.com/questions/690735/can-i-tell-if-im-in-an-scp-session-in-my-bashrc

Answer (score 13):

The **default** Ubuntu `.bashrc` contains the following snippet which already takes care of the problem:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac
```

Comment: shorter: `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`

Comment: The form provided in your answer is POSIX compatible. What you offer in your comment is not POSIX because of the use of `[[` feature. Not so problematic for a bashrc file ;) but you might want to be able to use it in another context/shell.

Answer (score 4):

In `.bashrc`, use STDERR as output instead:

```
echo "# Important Notice" >&2
```

**Update: do not use it!** We had an issue recently that a (closed source) tool failed due to an `echo` to STDERR in `.bashrc`. The tool (using `rcp`) expected no output at all, neither on STDOUT nor STDERR. And it stuck when it got the echo. Lesson learned: make separate accounts for humans and for machines (scripts), or just stop tattling via `.bashrc`.

Comment: "Make separate accounts for humans and for machines" is underrated.

Answer (score 2):

The most portable way of testing for an interactive shell seems to be:

```
test -t 0
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    # interactive
    ;
else
    # non-interactive
    ;
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

nneonneo's solution worked for me as well. But since my default shell is TCSH, I had to slightly edit the fix as follows (in .tcshrc):

```
if ( $?SSH_TTY ) then
    exec /bin/bash
endif
```

Just thought I would share for everyone's benefit.

Comment: I have cshrc and your solution works for me. Upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) or variant, drop a script that does the `echo`, or whatever you want, into /etc/profile.d/

Answer (score 0):

If you want echo statements as well, the from @Blauhirn's answer, you can keep placing your echo statement/s after the case condition.

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac

echo "Your Greeting/Warning Message/s here!"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if [ 0 -eq $(shopt -q login_shell; echo $?) ]; then
  echo "do something?"
fi
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/328396/145930)

Comment: It would be nice to provide some context for the OP.

Comment: Context and relevant information can already be extracted from other answers and the question itself. This is just another way of doing what is already understood, with a low signal-to-noise ratio.