# How to scp back to local when I've already sshed into remote machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

Often I face this situation: I sshed into a remote server and ran some programs, and I want to copy their output files back to my local machine. What I do is remember the file path on remote machine, exit the connection, then `scp user@remote:filepath .`

Obviously this is not optimal. What I'm looking for is a way to let me scp file back to local machine without exiting the connection. I did some searching, almost all results are telling me how to do scp from my local machine, which I already know.

Is this possible? Better still, is it possible without needing to know the IP address of my local machine?

Comment: Why don't you open another terminal and from this terminal launch your `scp` command while your `ssh` connection is still opened in another terminal? You can open as many connection as you want to the same remote machine through ssh.

Comment: you can :  `echo $(pwd)/*something` to have a full path list of the files to copy. Then you suspend the ssh connection with `[ctrl]+[z]`, returning to your original prompt, where you type the `scp`, then resume the ssh session with `fg` to put it back running in the foreground

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Given that you have an `sshd` running on your local machine, it's possible and you don't need to know your outgoing IP address. If SSH port forwarding is enabled, you can open a secure tunnel even when you already have an ssh connection opened, and without terminating it.

Assume you have an ssh connection to some server:

```
local $ ssh user@example.com
Password:
remote $ echo abc > abc.txt  # now we have a file here
```

OK now we need to copy that file back to our local server, and for some reason we don't want to open a new connection. OK, let's get the ssh command line by pressing `Enter ~C` (Enter, then tilde, then capital C):

```
ssh> help
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -D[bind_address:]port                  Request dynamic forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward
```

That's just like the regular `-L/R/D` options. We'll need `-R`, so we hit `Enter ~C` again and type:

```
ssh> -R 127.0.0.1:2222:127.0.0.1:22
Forwarding port.
```

Here we forward remote server's port 2222 to local machine's port 22 (and here is where you need the local SSH server to be started on port 22; if it's listening on some other port, use it instead of 22).

Now just run `scp` on a remote server and copy our file to remote server's port 2222 which is mapped to our local machine's port 22 (where our local `sshd` is running).

```
remote $ scp -P2222 abc.txt user@127.0.0.1:
user@127.0.0.1's password:
abc.txt                   100%    4     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

We are done!

```
remote $ exit
logout
Connection to example.com closed.
local $ cat abc.txt
abc
```

Tricky, but if you *really cannot* just run `scp` from another terminal, could help.

Comment: Can the flag `-R 127.0.0.1:2222:127.0.0.1:22` be issued when **starting** the SSH session? So I can add to my `.bashrc` the alias `alias ssh="ssh -R 127.0.0.1:2222:127.0.0.1:22"` on my local machine, and then write a bash function in the `.bashrc` of the remote machine whose contents look something like `scp -P2222 $1 user@127.0.0.1:$2`? That would make scp'ing from the remote machine very efficient. OP's motivation for this is mainly that scp'ing inside the local machine means I can't use tab completion on the file and must supply the entire pathname.

Comment: @LukeDavis Yes, you can add this option to your ssh command line. I guess OP's question was related to a situation where no special arrangements were made before making a connection.

Comment: One more question: the `2222` and `22` were examples right? So I could, for example, make the remote/local port numbers both `999`?

Comment: @LukeDavis sure you can. 22 is the default port for sshd but your service can be configured to listen to any port.

Comment: This is awesome.  But as someone who got here because he was looking for a simple way to do something without having to open another tab and do a new scp connection, this solution is very hilarious.

Comment: This post would be more useful if you explained how to know what ports to use.

Comment: Thank you. This is brilliant. I now really got my head around working with ssh forwarding. Excellent demonstration in minimal words.

Comment: I have an error : `connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused`

Comment: Just for clarification, it seems like this requires 2 connections to remote. Running the command to forward port on remote blocks my user input so I'd have to open a new remote tab to run the scp command. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7):

I found [this one-liner solution](https://superuser.com/a/768149/1000968) on SU to be a lot more straightforward than the accepted answer.    Since it uses an environmental variable for the local IP address, I think that it also satisfies the OP's request to not know it in advance.

based on that, here's a bash function to "DownLoad" a file (i.e. push from SSH session to a set location on the local machine)

```
function dl(){
    scp "$1" ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}:/home/<USER>/Downloads
}
```

Now I can just call `dl somefile.txt` while SSH'd into the remote and `somefile.txt` appears in my local Downloads folder.

extras:

- I use rsa keys (ssh-copy-id) to get around password prompt
- I found [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25132993/2433894) to prevent the local bashrc from being sourced on the scp call

Note: this requires SSH access to local machine from remote (is this often the case for anyone?)

Comment: For me I found the environment variable was `SSH_CLIENT`, not `CLIENT_IP`; I am running macOS sshing into Ubuntu.  OTOH, I wasn't able to get past my NAT without reconfiguring so I didn't find it worth the trouble to figure out and went another way.  Still, maybe knowing that it might be `SSH_CLIENT` instead of  `CLIENT_IP` will help someone else.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I have the same setup (macOS local, Ubuntu remote) and can confirm that CLIENT_IP is not set but SSH_CLIENT is set on the remote. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! (you're right) I thought that I had edited/responded before but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty good and most users should be able to work with them. However, I found the accepted answer a tad cumbersome and others not flexible enough. A VPN server in between was also causing trouble for me with figuring out IP addresses.

So, the workaround I use is to generate the required `scp` command on the remote system using the following function in my `.bashrc` file:

```
function getCopyCommand {
  echo "scp user@remote:$(pwd)/$1 ."
}
```

I find `rsync` to be more useful if the local system is almost a mirror of the remote server (including the username) and I require to copy the directory structure also.

```
function getCopyCommand {
  echo "rsync -rvPR user@remote:$(pwd)/$1 /"
}
```

The generated scp or rsync command is then simply pasted on my local terminal to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a local ssh server running in your machine, then you can just:

```
    scp [-r] local_content your_local_user@your_local_machine_ip:
```

Anyway, you don't need to close your remote connection to make a remote copy, just open another terminal and run scp there.