# Why using echo in .bashrc leads to non working rcp?

Tags: linux, ssh, echo, rcp

I have lately been working on a "scripts" project to isolate and improve maintainability of all the bash shell tools and third party software versions we need so you'd source this e.g. `/opt/dev/scripts/tools.sh` from your `.bashrc` and you get all up to date environment variables for software versions etc etc. As part of this exercise I thought it was a good idea to print a message in `tools.sh` displaying the current version of the scripts i.e.

```
echo "************* Running Scripts version $SCRIPTS_VERSION *************"
```

The problem is that after doing this. All tools including `rcp` would show this message and `rcp` did not work. Why? The only way to fix it was to print the message only when the script was executed from a terminal and not from others like ssh, rcp etc.

```
# only show version if running from a console, print only when 
# parent contains 'terminal' 
PARENT=`ps --no-heading -o %c -p $PPID`
if [ `echo $PARENT | grep 'terminal'` ]; then
  echo "************* Running Scripts version $SCRIPTS_VERSION *************"
fi
```

Can anyone explain why `rcp` stops working if my `.bashrc` prints a message using `echo`?

Comment: Try printing the information to standard error instead: `echo ... >&2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCP doesn't work when echo in .bashrc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc)

Comment: Indeed possible duplicate seems very similar ... however, it is nice to show the same problem occurs with a different tool in this case the `rcp` tool, or?