# scp does not return error nor copy

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to scp a file from my local machine to a server.
scp returns me a series of stars like this without copying any file:

```
[xx@xx ~]$ scp xx.tar xx@xx.xx:~
xx@xx.xx's password:                           
****************************************************************
```

So the first thing: I entered the password correctly.

I also checked to make sure that scp works with other servers (only not this one).

scp works on this server, meaning that I can pull files into the server from a terminal logged on. Errors only happen when I try to push files into the server from other places. I tried different machines, they are all the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCP doesn't work when echo in .bashrc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what happened. It is my .bashrc file that's missing the following statement:

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute paths.

In other words, try `~/xx.tar` IF IN FACT `xx.tar` in IN `~`! Otherwise maybe something like: `/absolute/path/to/xx.tar`